# regular expression - url with parameters

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a rule for URL Rewrite 2.0
my internal URL is

```
http://someserver.net/in40/data/getcase.ashx?type=Good&format=json
```

("in40" is an application)

I need the following URL to work

```
http://someserver.net/in40/data/getcase/Good?fmt=json
```

rule

```
<match url="^data/getcase/([_0-9a-z-]+)\?fmt=([_0-9a-z-]+)$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="data/getcase.ashx?type={R:1}&amp;format={R:2}" />
```

doesn't work

---

but if I change `\?fmt=` to `/`

```
<match url="^data/getcase/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)$" />
```

then the following URL works fine

```
http://someserver.net/in40/data/getcase/Good/json
```

---

How to make the rewrite rule for

```
http://someserver.net/in40/data/getcase/Good?fmt=json
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you needed the `^` giving the string you are matching is not at the start of the string...

Comment: it is start of the string. The base part of the URL is "http://someserver.net/in40/".

Comment: And, as I said, the ^data/getcase/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)$ works fine. (but I tried to remove the ^ symbol :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `[_0-9a-z-]+` in your regex doesn't allow `Good` as it starts with an upper `G`. One solution would be to make sure the `ignoreCase` option is turned on for the path.
The second issue is that the query string should be treated in the condition and not in the path. In your case, it would go as follow:

```
<rule name="My rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^data/getcase/([_0-9a-z-]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^fmt=([_0-9a-z-]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="data/getcase.ashx?type={R:1}&amp;format={C:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: thank you, the "ignoreCase" param should be there, but it still doesn't work. It looks like UrlRewrite 2.0 ignores the \? part. Because when I change it to \. then everything goes fine....... http://someserver.net/in40/data/getcase/Good.fmt=json

Comment: Thanks, cheesemacfly :) your rule definition works fine. I have added my solution, but I am going to choose your answer. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

My previous rule definitions was wrong and URL Rewrite mudule couldn't see the "?" symbol because I didn't have a "conditions" section and I had to include it. And even after that I had wrong "input" parameter in rule definition - {QUERY_STRING}. When the module "sees" the

```
<add input="{QUERY_STRING}.....
```

string then it will search for {QUERY_STRING} which is a part of URL right AFTER the "?" symbol :)
I have replaced {QUERY_STRING} with {REQUEST_URI} to match entire URL instead
The following example works for me.

```
<rule name="Boo" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.+)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="data/getcase/([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)\?fmt=([_0-9A-Za-z-]+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="data/getcase.ashx?type={C:1}&amp;format={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex engine needs a backslash in front of the question mark to interpret it as a literal rather than the optional quantifier, which is why you'll have to escape the backslash itself: `\\?` This process is called double-escaping.

When writing regexes in C#, you usually use the `@` sign in front of the pattern string so you don't have to double-escape backslashes.